# Using wikipedia lua modules in a script

Tags: macos, lua, mediawiki, scribunto

OK, so, let me first make it clear that I have no idea how Lua really works, never written more than 10 lines of code in it and that I'm generally confused about how MediaWiki + Scribunto + Lua works...

So...

I have this wiktionary module/template:

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Module:pl-IPA&action=edit

It looks to me like perfectly valid lua code.

When I try to run some simple example (e.g. calling the function `export.convert_to_IPA("something")`), Lua seems to complain that it doesn't know what `mw` is.

From what I know, `mw` stands for MediaWiki and is a reference to the Scribunto module.

The question is... how do I find and import this `mw` module in a simple Lua script running from the terminal... with the Lua interpreter, on Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't use `mw` in standalone Lua without MediaWiki. Almost all of the functions it provides are callbacks into MediaWiki's PHP. However, it looks like you just want to use `convert_to_IPA` rather than `template_IPA`, and the only usage of `mw` that the former has is this line: `for ch in mw.ustring.gmatch(mw.ustring.lower(word), ".") do`. You're lucky: `mw.ustring` is the exception to the rule, and it does have a pure-Lua implementation: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Scribunto/tree/master/includes/engines/LuaCommon/lualib/ustring

Here's an example of how you can use it (assuming your current directory contains both `pl-IPA.lua` and the `ustring` directory I linked):

```
$ lua5.1
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> mw = {ustring = require 'ustring/ustring'}
> export = require 'pl-IPA'
> =export.convert_to_IPA("something")
sɔˈmɛt.xʲink
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Awesome answer. In the meantime, I've also found this: (basically, it's part of a Wiktionary parser in Python - pretty much what I'm working on, but in Ruby) https://github.com/tatuylonen/wikitextprocessor